# Probability of sampling all individuals in a population

Tags: probability, experiment-design

If someone could help me answer this or point me in the write direction I would greatly appreciate it.

If I have 8000 different balls and there are 100 of each ball (800,000 total balls) and each time I reach into the jar I grab 12 balls.

How do I determine the probability of sampling at least one of each balls after 667 (8,000 / 22  = 666.67) draws without replacement?

After 1,333 draws without replacement?

Comment: Do you replace the balls after each grab or not?  If you do, then you can find several answers (and generalizations) by searching our site for "coupon collector."

Comment: I don’t replace the balls after sampling. I’ll will update the question to include without replacement. Thanks!